# Manage dotfiles inhibiting hardcoded paths?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, dotfiles

Today I decided to manage and push my dotfiles in the repository. The motivation is to reuse the same dotfiles on multiple mac machines and ubuntu server machines.

I currently have thought of this structure:

```
├── bash
│   ├── aliases
│   ├── config
│   └── env
├── bash_profile
├── bashrc
├── hgrc
├── src
│   └── link.py
└── vimrc
```

`link.py` runs and creates symlinks for `bashrc` and `bash_profile` from `~` to where-ever this repository is cloned to.

**Problem: 1**

my `bashrc` contents:

```
source bash/env
source bash/config
source bash/aliases
```

The problem is because the paths are relative, the files are not found. I don't want to use an absolute path because then I lose the flexibility to clone the repository anywhere I like.

similarly, my `bash_profile` contents:

```
source ./bashrc                       # same problem!
source ~/.bashrc
```

since I previously symlinked `~/.bashrc` to `dotfiles/bashrc` I can reach it. But it still seems like a dirty hack to me.

**Problem: 2**

Where should I keep my paths which are custom to particular machine. Surely I don't want to put them in the repository and mess up every other system as well. Currently my custom paths are in `~/.profile`. I am thinking to source it from `bash/env` with an `if` to check if it exists then use it otherwise not.

Would love to hear better approaches

Comment: Consider asking user questions on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not get much response here, I have resorted to expanding my `src/link.py` to symlink `~/.bash` to `dotfiles/bash` so that I can reach `bash/*` using `~/.bash/*`

I have also added a ignore list in my link.py to ignore `.hg`, `bin` directories so that they are not symlinked when doing a `os.listdir()`.

I am still looking for a solution for my second problem, although I read somewhere that I can use separate branches for my dotfiles for each machine which have specific customization needs, and it seems to be the most closest clean solution right now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using symlinks, and not consider it as "dirty hack". Previously i was simple copying all files (and still doing this for the some files (not bash)), and because all files are for $HOME/.something i was used "$HOME" (not '~', because '~' was not expanded in double quotes but $HOME yes.)

Answer (score 0):

It's really late reply, but still I will recommend you to check *DFM* (dotfiles manager). *DFM* addresses the problem you have in a very clean way:

- Here is my dotfiles selection using dfm: [vicente's dotfiles](https://github.com/vicentebolea/dotfiles)
- Github official repository [DFM site](https://github.com/justone/dfm)